# Can the Auto suggest results count be changed in SXA?

Tags: sxa, content-search

I'm using Sitecore 9 update 1 with SXA 1.7, I configured the auto suggester in the Solr, the `suggest.count` is 30 and the maximum predictive results count for the SXA search box is 30 also, but the returning results is always 5 although there is more data indexed in the Solr, I tried many things like changing numbers or removing it but still the same.

Here is my configuration for the auto suggester :

```
<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
                    <lst name="suggester">
                      <str name="name">sxaSuggester</str>
                      <str name="lookupImpl">BlendedInfixLookupFactory</str>
                      <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
                      <str name="contextField">_language</str>
                      <str name="field">suggestion_s</str>
                      <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">text_suggester</str>
                      <str name="payloadField">templatedisplayname_s</str>
                      <str name="buildOnStartup">true</str>
                      <str name="buildOnCommit">false</str>
                    </lst>
        </searchComponent>
        <requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy" >
                    <lst name="defaults">
                      <str name="suggest.dictionary">sxaSuggester</str>
                      <str name="suggest">true</str>
                      <str name="suggest.onlyMorePopular">true</str>
                      <str name="suggest.count">30</str>
                      <str name="suggest.collate">true</str>
                    </lst>
                    <arr name="components">
                      <str>suggest</str>
                    </arr>
        </requestHandler>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's hardcoded to have 5 suggestions. It definitely shouldn't be done that way and I will register a task in our backlog to change it and make it configurable.

As a workaround, you could override `SolrSuggester` or implement your own suggester by creating a class which implements `ISuggester` interface. At the end just replace SXA implementation by your one in the DI container.

You can pass a number of suggestions like that:

```
SuggestHandlerQueryOptions options = new SuggestHandlerQueryOptions
{
    Parameters = new SuggestParameters
    {
        Count = NUMBER_OF_SUGGESTIONS
    }
}
```

Investigate `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.VersionSpecific.Services.SolrSuggester` to have a full picture how the implementation should look like.

Comment: Thanks so much, I implemented my own suggester, but need to know where to reference it from Sitecore configuration.

Comment: We are registering it in the `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.VersionSpecific.config` file - section services. But what you need to do is to replace existing implementation by your own one, you can do it in the C# code (a lot of examples, just google it).

Comment: Great, I did it and it returns the count I desired, but still only 5 results are rendered, I checked the solr request and it's correct, but in the component-search-box.js, the suggestion: function (data) (which render the suggestion results)are called 5 times only.
Is the count 5 is hard-coded somewhere else ?

Comment: I don't think so. Ensure that you've properly replaced SXA implementation in the DI container.

Comment: I found it out, in file typeahead.js at line 1723 :
suggestions.slice(0, that.limit - rendered),
it selects the first 5 elements as limit = 5, I don't know its importance so I removed the slice() function.

Comment: It's a 3rd party plugin which we use. It's not something written by us. But thanks for the information as I was not aware of it.